# Laravel 5.2 Validator: limiting unique field check to specific user

Tags: php, validation, laravel, artisan-migrate

I am trying to limit the required:unique validator in my Laravel 5.2 app to checking uniqueness of my 'slug' column against only the table results of a specific user_id. In other words, the slug does need to be unique, but only on a per-user basis. I've got it working for the store() function, with the following code:

```
'slug' => 'required|unique:contents,slug,NULL,id,user_id,' . Auth::id()
```

That works just fine. However, I can't get the update() function to work the same, because I can't get the validator to stop checking unique against the result of the entry that's currently being updated. The code I'm currently using is:

```
'slug' => 'required|unique:contents,slug,' . $content->slug . ',id,user_id,' . Auth::id()
```

That code doesn't look right to me, but I've tried several variants and none of them work how I would like. To my mind, I would think that this would work:

```
'slug' => 'required|unique:contents,id,' . $content->id . ',user_id,' . Auth::id()
```

But it doesn't. Does anybody know what my problem is here? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the second bit of code, are you aware that you have `$content->slug`, rather than `$content->id`? Other than that minor error, I would expect that second code to work

Comment: Yeah I didn't think the second line looked right either, the third line, which is: 'slug' => 'required|unique:contents,id,' . $content->id . ',id,user_id,' . Auth::id() is the one that I expect to work, but it doesn't. It allows me to update the slug to one that already exists for that user.

Comment: The last line of code is missing `,id`, perhaps that's why it's not working. Try: `'required|unique:contents,id,' . $content->id . ',id,user_id,' . Auth::id()`

Comment: My bad, Jonathon, I did make a typo in the third line in my question. The correct version was in my previous comment, though. The correct answer was from Jody, below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to give the right answer without knowing the actual attribute names in your model.  The validator supports the following parameters

```
unique:{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}
```

where:

`{0}` = table name being validated

`{1}` = column name being validated

`{2}` = Id value of row in `{0}` to skip validation

`{3}` = name of primary key column in `{0}`

`{4}` = name of additional filter column in `{0}`

`{5}` = value for additional filter column

So, it seems we clearly have the values for `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}` and `{5}`.  I am not sure from your question information what the correct values for `{3}` and `{4}` are.  If I was to take a guess, I would write the validator rule like this:

```
'slug' => 'required|unique:contents,slug,' . $content->id . ',id,user_id,' . Auth::id()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the validator param definitions. I hadn't seen those anywhere, not even on the Laravel site. I get it now. Thanks again!